# Redirect after comment submit according to value of query string in comment form URL?

Tags: 7, hooks, redirection

For redirecting user to some page after comment submit my below code is working fine :

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == "comment_node_link_form") {
      $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
  }
}


function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'newsroom/en';
}
```

For Comment links I am sending some query string in comment form URL and want to redirect to user to page after comment according to query string value, How can we fetch the query string value to pass it to redirect on `hook_submit`

```
http://www.example.com/comment/reply/208943?destination=newsroom#comment-form

http://www.example.com/comment/reply/208943?destination=sections#comment-form
```

How can we fetch value of **destination**  and pass it to **redirect** in **hook_submit**

Please suggest ! Thanks!

**UPDATE :**  I have tried adding hidden field but not able to access it in hook_submit it shows null :

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
       if ($form_id == "comment_node_link_form") {

           $form['redirect_to'] = array(
             '#type' => 'hidden',
             '#value' => $_GET['destination'],
           );

          $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks at @Pierre.Vriens , please check answer I posted, this is how I solved this for me. Hope you will found this an interesting approach. And hope I am not moving in any wrong direction.

Comment: Well, that appears to be another solution (haven't tried it, but if it works for you, why not!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After More deep debugging I found that **action** of comment from is set to

> comment/reply/nodeid

So with below URL's:

> http://www.example.com/comment/reply/208943?destination=newsroom#comment-form
>
> http://www.example.com/comment/reply/208943?destination=sections#comment-form

My query string variable **destination**  is lost or either at form submit it shows null because from moves to action URL where no query string was set.

To solve this I have added query string in action URL which works very well :

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == "comment_node_link_form") {
      $form['#action'] = $form['#action'] . '?destination=' . $_GET['destination'];
  }
}
```

ie: All I have to do is add required query string to `$form['#action']`

Hope this will help any one who is trying similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['redirect_query_string'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'YourRedirectpagecallbackfunction',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    //'access argument' =>  array('Download CSV'),
    'type'  => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

In your form submit write:

if(isset($_GET["redirect_query_string"])){
    return YourRedirectpagecallbackfunction();
  }

function YourRedirectpagecallbackfunction(){
......your redirect url......
}
```

Comment: "link" is my content type name and I am trying to send argument to hook_submit from my content type comment submit form. Not able to to understand clearly your code, that will be helpful if you can explain little more. Thanks!